# resizing an image in tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

the following code plays a given video file on a tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


root = Tk()
main_label = Label(root)
main_label.grid()

# Capture from camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")


# function for video streaming
def video_stream():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    main_label.configure(image=tk_img)
    main_label.tk_img = tk_img
    main_label.after(20, video_stream)


video_stream()
root.mainloop()
```

my question is how can I resize the video to be played in a 500 by 500 resolution for example?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315349/how-to-resize-frames-from-video-with-aspect-ratio/58362647) and [this](https://theailearner.com/2018/11/15/changing-video-resolution-using-opencv-python/)

Comment: Did you try `cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, (500, 500))` after the sentence `ret, frame = cap.read()`?

Comment: thank you both so much! @Ahx that's exactly what i needed! thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to mention a possible problem.

Always check whether the `frame` returns or not. Otherwise your application will crash.

```py
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
```

Now `resize` your frame

```py
# function for video streaming
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, (500, 500))
```

Correct Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


root = Tk()
main_label = Label(root)
main_label.grid()

# Capture from camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")


# function for video streaming
def video_stream():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        cv2image = cv2.resize(cv2image, (500, 500))
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        main_label.configure(image=tk_img)
        main_label.tk_img = tk_img
        main_label.after(20, video_stream)


video_stream()
root.mainloop()
```